# 507 Insufficient Storage in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, xmlhttprequest, handsontable

I am working in Handsontable project,
in after change function i want to send data in ajax to controller,

but in bulk copy paste time ajax giving 507 insufficient storage error in response,

how can i clear this problem.

Comment: Looks like you've reached the quota for your local browser storage.Which browser are you using to run the application ?

Comment: i am using crome

Comment: Check the browser storage and if not available remove some data from localstorage and check once. Alos edit with your code and error snapshot.

Comment: if i change maxAllowedContentLength for my server, it gives any solution?